# Subdivide a numerical vector with a normal distribution

Tags: python, statistics, data-cleaning, normalization

I have a numerical array of prices values. I'd like to do classification on this parameter, so I'd like to create a certain number of classes with the same granularity. I'd like to create a generalized function that given the array and the number of classes i'd like to have it automatically return the price intervals for those classes. 
Currently this is my price attribute:

```
df_cleaned.price.describe()
>>>
count    122668.000000
mean      11253.349594
std        7856.513917
min        1010.000000
25%        4995.000000
50%        8995.000000
75%       15965.000000
max       34991.000000
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

And I created a function manually to create 6 classes and it looks like this:

```
def normalize_price(df): 
    cond = [
        (df['price'] >= 1000) & (df['price'] <= 4999),
        (df['price'] >= 5000) & (df['price'] <= 8999),
        (df['price'] >= 9000) & (df['price'] <= 15999),
        (df['price'] >= 16000) & (df['price'] <= 24999), 
        (df['price'] >= 25000) & (df['price'] <= 34000),
        (df['price'] >= 34001) & (df['price'] <= 40000) 
    ]

    choice = [
        1000,
        5000,
        9000,
        16000,
        25000,
        35000,
    ]

    df['price'] = np.select(cond, choice, df['price'])
    return df
```

Can anyone help me improvint this function? pls thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing the method `cut` in pandas [(documentation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

This method does exactly what you want, if you want to separate a dataframe into `n` equal-sized bins or manually specify the ranges.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([10, 50, 99, 140, 250, 300, 450, 499]), columns=['price'])

bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 100), (100, 300), (300, 500)])
df['price'] = pd.cut(df['price'], bins)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

You can simply specify the number of bins you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([10, 50, 99, 140, 250, 300, 450, 499]), columns=['price'])

df['price'] = pd.cut(df['price'], bins=3)
```

Output:

[image: output]

I hope this helps improve your code.